# How to create indexes with elasticsearch-model, bulk index doesn't work

Tags: ruby, activerecord, elasticsearch, activemodel

I use `elasticsearch-model` gem to integrate elasticsearch with activerecord, I am using this module:

```
#http://www.codinginthecrease.com/news_article/show/409843?referrer_id=
module PostImport

  def self.import
    Post.find_in_batches do |posts|
      bulk_index(posts)
    end
  end


  def self.prepare_records(posts)
    posts.map do |post|
      { index: { _id: post.id, data: post.as_indexed_json } }
    end
  end

  def self.delete_index
    Post.__elasticsearch__.client
      .indices.delete index: ::Post.__elasticsearch__.index_name rescue nil
  end

  def self.create_index
    Post.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
  end

  def self.bulk_index(posts)
    Post.__elasticsearch__.client
      .bulk({
             index: ::Post.__elasticsearch__.index_name,
             type: ::Post.__elasticsearch__.document_type,
             body: prepare_records(posts),
             refresh: true
            })
  end
end
```

According to [elasticsearch-model example](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/examples/activerecord_article.rb#L49)

It uses this to create indexes in bulk:

```
client.bulk index: 'articles',
            type:  'article',
            body:  Article.all.as_json.map { |a| { index: { _id: a.delete('id'), data: a } } },
            refresh: true
```

But this raises:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound: [404] {"error":"IndexMissingException[[posts] missing]","status":404}
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:132:in `__raise_transport_error'
```

So the equivalent code in my module: `PostImport::import` raises this exception, If I call `Post.__elasticsearch__.create_index!` first, and then do import, it works fine.

What is the proper way to initialize elasticsearch and create indexes with `elasticsearch-model` gem?

Comment: Have you turned off auto_create_index ?

Comment: This is my first try, and I have zero configuration. @FrederickCheung

Comment: Hey @user3995789 can you resolve this ?, I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the elasticsearch-rails gem for this. See documentation here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails

To facilitate importing data from your models into Elasticsearch, require the task definition in your application, eg. create the lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake file with this content:

```
require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'
```

To import the records from your Article model for the first time and create the index, run this:

```
$ bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Article' FORCE=y
```